# How to use NSAutoreleasePool

Tags: iphone, nsautoreleasepool

If I use NSAutoreleasePool, every object created inside the pool should never be released mannually?It will be released when the pool is drained?

```
- (void) backgroundRequest{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        urlList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        target = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      {
    //do stuff in here  

    }
    [urlList release];
    [target release];

    [pool release];
}
```

Are the above lines correct or I should remove `[urlList release]` and `[target release]`?
*IMPORTANT*: I will wait an explanantion and an answer.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

An autorelease pool only works when you have objects using the Autorelease methods.

If you're using this:

```
urlList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then you will want to do your own release, yes.  However if you do this:

```
urlList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Then you can let the NSAutorelease pool handle that.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to release `urlList` and `target`, then you can use this code:

```
- (void) backgroundRequest
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        urlList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
        target = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
      {
    //do stuff in here  

    }

    [pool release];
}
```

Hope this helps you.

The point is that AutoreleasePool takes care of those allocations which have been autoreleased with the keyword `autorelease` So if you use that keyword then you don't need to release it. It is released when the AutoreleasePool gets released.

If you need more information then please leave me a message below.

Comment: What is the need for writing pool then if we are doing autoreleasing. Would you please explain ? Is it right that it is not much good to write autorelease pool on main thread. (According to Serious Sam below).

Comment: @ArpitParekh: Yes Arpit it is not preferable to use autorelease but as we are using Background task, we have used autorelease pool. Also yes thanks for pointing out the wrong code. Thanks again

Comment: Hi parth, now your edited code is not right.your previous code was right. My concern was just that why we are writing the autorelease pool on main method. Which you have told about background tasks.It is right. Thanks

Comment: @ArpitParekh: Hi Arpit, this method `backgroundRequest` can be also called from NSThread. its name suggest that it is a background request. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: :ya thanks buddy.I forgot to consider backgroundrequest method 'name' in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I second the answer from @Brayden. I would like to add up to that.
Generally every thread has its autorelease pool. See your .main file for instance. It has got an autorelease pool associated with it. So that way your main thread has got an autorelease pool. 
Now when you spawn another thread, ie try to run some methods on another thread, and if your gonna use class methods for common initialization.

`eg: NSString *strTem = [NSString stringWithString:AnotherString];`

Such is the case where autorelease will be used, and for such functions(methods) you need to have a separate autorelease pool of your own.

Hope this helps some more.